# Связи между моделями ExtJS 6.0.2

Tags: json, extjs, model, связи, модель-данных

Возможно ли образовать связь между моделями (User и Group) на фреймворке ExtJS 6.0.2, если данные для моделей будут поступать из разных url, в json формате такого вида?

Пример JSON ответа:

url: data/groups.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "groups": [
        {"name": "admins", "id":1, "description": "full access"},
        {"name": "users", "id":2, "description": "limit access"},
        {"name": "guests", "id":3, "description": "others"},
    ]
}
```

url: data/users.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {
            "name":"Ted",
            "age": 22,
            "gender":"Male",
            "id":1,
            "group_id": 2
        },
        {
            "name":"Ed",
            "age" : 33,
            "gender":"Male",
            "id":2,
            "group_id": 1
        },
        {
            "name":"Test",
            "age" : 44,
            "gender":"Female",
            "id":3,
            "group_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Если это возможно, опишите детально что куда и зачем. (желательно чтоб связи подхватывались автоматически по полю group_id)
Есть небольшой набросок, но он не работает: http://pastie.org/10822311

Comment: Рекомендую пошерстить мануал на тему Ext.data.schema.Association